# Add data at the end of existing data in resource file

Tags: c#, winforms, resx

I want to add data at the end of existing data in resource file on the click of button in windows form.
I have a windows form with 3 text boxes -

```
text_box1: Name
text_box2: Value
text_box3: Comments
and a button named as Save.
```

code for button:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myMethod.Create(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
        }
```

Method to add data in resource file:

```
public class myMethod
    {
        public static void Create(string myName, string myValue, string myComment)
        {
            try
            {
                ResXResourceReader resxReader = new ResXResourceReader(@"D:\Validator_Tool\resx\resx\myres.resx");
                resxReader.UseResXDataNodes = true;
                IDictionaryEnumerator data = resxReader.GetEnumerator();

            while (data.MoveNext())
            {
                ResXResourceWriter resxWriter = new ResXResourceWriter(@"D:\Validator_Tool\resx\resx\myres.resx");
                var node = new ResXDataNode(myName, myValue);
                node.Comment = myValue;
                resxWriter.AddResource(node);
                resxWriter.Close();
            }

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException caught)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Source: " + caught.Source + " Message: " + caught.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me in this problem to add data in resource file because with this code my data is overwrite with existing data but I want my data should append at the end of the existing data. 
This code giving me exception too while using IDictionaryEnumerator exception is:

> System.InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a snippet, to add a new line to your resx and keep the old records:

```
var reader = new ResXResourceReader("filename");
var node = reader.GetEnumerator();
var writer = new ResXResourceWriter("filename");
while (node.MoveNext())
{
    writer.AddResource(node.Key.ToString(), node.Value.ToString());
}
var newNode = new ResXDataNode("name", "value");
writer.AddResource(newNode);
writer.Generate();
writer.Close();
```

This will re-write your old lines and add your new line.

Comment: I have used this code but with this code my Comment removed form previous Entry.

Comment: I think this would throw an exception when you attempt to create a writer from same file as being used by the reader.